# Response.Redirect doesn't run using Razor in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session, razor, response.redirect

```
@{
    if (Session["LoginType"] == null)
    {
       Response.Redirect("~/Account/Login", true);
    }

}
```

If the Session expires, the Session["LoginType"] becomes null.
I can catch that.
But the next line to redirect to the login page again, doesn't work.
Yellow code line in break mode just stops on it, then moves on to next lines of code (that gives an error because the Session["LoginType"] is null.

Any ideas? Am I coding this wrong? Not really an expert at this MVC/Razor stuff.

Comment: This should be done in the controller, not the view.

Comment: Ah, you are correct. And it works in the Controller when I put this in the Action that loads the page: return RedirectToAction("Login","Account");
If you make your comment an answer I will make it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be performing this type of logic in the controller rather than the view.

Comment: Thank you! I accept this as the answer. It set me straight. I also proceeded and found this jQuery way to pop up a message and give user a chance to continue, logoff, or it would just logoff itself.
https://github.com/travishorn/jquery-sessionTimeout